# How to find JavaScript process in client's browser?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have this flow in my C# and simple JavaScript app:

1. Call server-side function
2. After finishing, call an AJAX in JavaScript and redirect to an URL with some data
3. Inside the URL, in the client's code an API is calling and doing some business.

Now the client is claiming the AJAX is calling me multiple and therefore my Api is calling multiple.
Due to executing JS is not server-side, how can I find out how many times AJAX is calling?

Comment: Developer tools network tab is showing all requests made.

Comment: You need not to call the endpoint that you describe in step 1 when the client recieves the response from that endpoint in step 2. In other words if endpoint_of_step_1 is being called from the client you will have an infinite redirect issue.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze when js is executing in the client's computer and its browser how can I find what is happening?

Comment: You could write logs to your server or work with your client by remoting into their machine, ask the client to provide a screenshot etc...

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze Thanks dear, is there any library or anything to log js in client-side?

Comment: `fetch("myApiEndpoint", { method: "POST", headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, body: JSON.stringify(log) });`?